# c++ how to make pointers point to arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to create a pointerlist that points to the previous and next elements. I also want each element to contain an array. How do I define this in the class and/or add the array to the elements of the list

```
class codes {
    public:
        int code[];
        codes* next;
        codes* previous;
};//codes

void addtolist(codes* & entrance, int k[]) {
    codes* c;
    c = new codes;
    c->code[] = k;
    c->next = entrance;
    if(c->next != NULL){
        c->next->previous=c;
    }//if
    c->previous = NULL;
    entrance = c;
}//addtolist
```

Comment: Just use a pointer, a pointer can point to one or more values e.g. an array.

Answer (score 2):

You create a pointer to some class object like this:

```
SomeClass *ptr = new SomeClass();
```

or

```
 SomeClass a;
 SomeClass *ptr = &a;
```

To define array inside your structure, just do inside your structure:

```
int arr[32];
```

Just note this is array of fized size. If you want array with dynamic size
declare:

```
int * arr;
```

inside your structure, and then at some point make it point to
array objects:

```
obj.arr = new int[SIZE];
```

You'll have to call `delete[]` in the above case when done with array.
That said it might be tricky (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)) to have class which manages dynamic memory internally,
you might prefer array with fixed size.

Do member wise copy of array elements instead of this:

```
c->code[] = k; // You can't assign like this since code is not a pointer
```

Comment: He does modify `entrance` parameter so he needs to pass a reference in current code.

Comment: @Slava: Ok I see it now, I'll modify

Answer (score 2):

An array is a pointer of sorts already.  In C/C++, if I have an array:

```
int arr[10]
```

then array access

```
arr[2];
```

is just another way of dereferenced pointer access

```
*(arr + 2);
```

An array can be passed to a pointer

```
int getSecond(int* a) {
    return a[2];
}
getSecond(arr);
```

So, if you class is holding an array whose lifetime is managed somewhere else, all you need is a pointer:

```
class codes {
    public:
        int* code;
        codes* next;
        codes* previous;
};//codes
```

Now if you want your codes class to actually manage the lifetime of the array, or copy the values into the class, you will have to do some additional work.